# SharePoint-hosted App - Retrieving items in host web with REST from app web with enabled fine-grained permissions

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint-hosted app which is querying list in host web. This list has enabled fine-grained permissions (item level security) and I am site collection admin.

When I try to query items (with cross domain library), only items created by me are returned. But if the query is "standard", it returns all items.

Cross domain call:

```
https://tenant-appweb.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('My List')/items?&$select=Id,Title,Author/Title&$expand=Author/Title&@target='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/hostweb'
```

Standard call:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/hostweb/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('My List')/items?&$select=Id,Title,Author/Title&$expand=Author/Title
```

Is it known behavior or I'm missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself. The App has only Write permission to web and it requires at least Manage.

[image: App permissions]